# Error while building florisboard open source on mac Os Sonoma. ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed

Tags: android, macos, gcc, cmake, gnu-make

Here is the link to open source:

https://github.com/florisboard/florisboard

I am trying to build on mac and it continueously giving the error while building.
It would be great if anyone can have clone of this project and can check if its working on mac. Thank you

Error Logs:

```
> Task :app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a][florisboard-native]
C/C++: ninja: Entering directory `/Users/mac/Work/AndroidProjects/fasttype/app/.cxx/Debug/2f3r6z3n/arm64-v8a'
C/C++: configure: error: in `/Users/mac/Work/AndroidProjects/fasttype/app/.cxx/Debug/2f3r6z3n/arm64-v8a/nlp/icu4c/.intermediate/host':

> Task :app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a][florisboard-native] FAILED
C/C++: configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
C/C++: See `config.log' for more details
C/C++: [6/107] Building CXX object utils/CMakeFiles/utils.dir/log.cpp.o
C/C++: [7/107] Building CXX object nlp/external/fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/src/format.cc.o
C/C++: ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
[6/107] Building CXX object utils/CMakeFiles/utils.dir/log.cpp.o
[7/107] Building CXX object nlp/external/fmt/CMakeFiles/fmt.dir/src/format.cc.o
```

[image]

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)

project(florisboard)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories(.)

### FlorisBoard ###
add_subdirectory(utils)
add_subdirectory(nlp)

add_library(
        florisboard-native
        SHARED
        dev_patrickgold_florisboard_FlorisApplication.cpp
)

target_compile_options(florisboard-native PRIVATE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fexceptions)
target_link_libraries(
        # Destination
        florisboard-native

        # Sources
        android
        log
        fl::nlp::core
        utils
)
```

build.gradle:

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2022 Patrick Goldinger
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Suppress needed until https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-19369 is fixed
@file:Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION")

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.File

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.agp.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.mannodermaus.android.junit5)
    alias(libs.plugins.mikepenz.aboutlibraries)
}

android {
    namespace = "dev.patrickgold.florisboard"
    compileSdk = 33
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
    ndkVersion = "25.2.9519653"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf(
            "-Xallow-result-return-type",
            "-opt-in=kotlin.contracts.ExperimentalContracts",
            "-Xjvm-default=all-compatibility",
        )
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "dev.patrickgold.florisboard"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 90
        versionName = "0.4.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_COMMIT_HASH", "\"${getGitCommitHash()}\"")

        ksp {
            arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            arg("room.incremental", "true")
            arg("room.expandProjection", "true")
        }

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                targets("florisboard-native")
                cppFlags("-std=gnu++20", "-stdlib=libc++")
                arguments(
                    "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_API=" + minSdk.toString(),
                    "-DICU_ASSET_EXPORT_DIR=" + project.file("src/main/assets/icu4c").absolutePath,
                    "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=false",
                    "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static",
                )
            }
        }

        ndk {
            abiFilters += listOf("armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a")
        }

        sourceSets {
            maybeCreate("main").apply {
                assets {
                    srcDirs("src/main/assets")
                }
                java {
                    srcDirs("src/main/kotlin")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            // We disable language split because FlorisBoard does not use
            // runtime Google Play Service APIs and thus cannot dynamically
            // request to download the language resources for a specific locale.
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.androidx.compose.compiler.get()
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path("src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt")
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        named("debug") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix = "-debug-${getGitCommitHash(short = true)}"

            isDebuggable = true
            isJniDebuggable = false

            ndk {
                // For running FlorisBoard on the emulator
                // abiFilters += listOf("x86", "x86_64")
            }

            resValue("mipmap", "floris_app_icon", "@mipmap/ic_app_icon_debug")
            resValue("mipmap", "floris_app_icon_round", "@mipmap/ic_app_icon_debug_round")
            resValue("drawable", "floris_app_icon_foreground", "@drawable/ic_app_icon_debug_foreground")
            resValue("string", "floris_app_name", "FlorisBoard Debug")
        }

        create("beta") {
            applicationIdSuffix = ".beta"
            versionNameSuffix = "-alpha04"

            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true

            resValue("mipmap", "floris_app_icon", "@mipmap/ic_app_icon_beta")
            resValue("mipmap", "floris_app_icon_round", "@mipmap/ic_app_icon_beta_round")
            resValue("drawable", "floris_app_icon_foreground", "@drawable/ic_app_icon_beta_foreground")
            resValue("string", "floris_app_name", "FlorisBoard Beta")
        }

        named("release") {
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true

            resValue("mipmap", "floris_app_icon", "@mipmap/ic_app_icon_stable")
            resValue("mipmap", "floris_app_icon_round", "@mipmap/ic_app_icon_stable_round")
            resValue("drawable", "floris_app_icon_foreground", "@drawable/ic_app_icon_stable_foreground")
            resValue("string", "floris_app_name", "@string/app_name")
        }

        create("benchmark") {
            initWith(getByName("release"))
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
            matchingFallbacks += listOf("release")

            ndk {
                // For running FlorisBoard on the emulator
                abiFilters += listOf("x86", "x86_64")
            }
        }
    }

    aboutLibraries {
        configPath = "app/src/main/config"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            isIncludeAndroidResources = true
        }
        unitTests.all {
            it.useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.accompanist.flowlayout)
    implementation(libs.accompanist.systemuicontroller)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.autofill)
    implementation(libs.androidx.collection.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.runtime.livedata)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.splashscreen)
    implementation(libs.androidx.emoji2)
    implementation(libs.androidx.emoji2.views)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.profileinstaller)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.room.runtime)
    implementation(libs.cache4k)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
    implementation(libs.mikepenz.aboutlibraries.core)
    implementation(libs.mikepenz.aboutlibraries.compose)
    implementation(libs.patrickgold.compose.tooltip)
    implementation(libs.patrickgold.jetpref.datastore.model)
    implementation(libs.patrickgold.jetpref.datastore.ui)
    implementation(libs.patrickgold.jetpref.material.ui)

    testImplementation(libs.equalsverifier)
    testImplementation(libs.kotest.assertions.core)
    testImplementation(libs.kotest.extensions.roboelectric)
    testImplementation(libs.kotest.property)
    testImplementation(libs.kotest.runner.junit5)

    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.core)
}

fun getGitCommitHash(short: Boolean = false): String {
    if (!File(".git").exists()) {
        return "null"
    }

    val stdout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        if (short) {
            commandLine("git", "rev-parse", "--short", "HEAD")
        } else {
            commandLine("git", "rev-parse", "HEAD")
        }
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow requires error log to be included into the question post as **text**, not as an *image*. I would expect a user with over 1k reputation to be aware of that. The question post also lacks for details about how exactly you are building the project.

Comment: So you got the error message `configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables` and following suggestion ``See `config.log' for more details``. Have you checked that file (`config.log`)?

Comment: Logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GAGw0EKbbaYpuMtsK0MUo5hsT4LyTW3m/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please remove the `gnu-make` tag from this question.  You are using cmake, not makefiles.

Comment: Acc to open source documentation, gnu make is required to build the project. Thats why I added this tag.